# How to make checkbox clickable only on checkbox?

Tags: html, css

```html
 <label style="display: flex; align-items: center">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        style="margin-right: 12px"
                        class=""
                        checked="checked"
                        name="sameadr"
                      />
                      <span class="reach-out"> Reach out to me on</span
                      ><span class="whatsapp-icon"></span>
                      <span class="whatsapp-content"> Whatsapp</span>
                    </label>
```

I have a checkbox, But the issue is, If i click on the content also, i am able to check the checkbox.

But i need the checkbox to select, if i click on checkbox only not on the content.

Comment: so why use a label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a label, replace it with something else.

Nesting the input in the label **automatically** associates it with the label.

```html
 <div style="display: flex; align-items: center">
                      <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        style="margin-right: 12px"
                        class=""
                        checked="checked"
                        name="sameadr"
                      />
                      <span class="reach-out"> Reach out to me on</span
                      ><span class="whatsapp-icon"></span>
                      <span class="whatsapp-content"> Whatsapp</span>
                    </div>
```

Alternatively, move the label to **after** the input, just don't link to two together.

```html
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right: 12px" class="" checked="checked" name="sameadr" />
<label>
                      <span class="reach-out"> Reach out to me on</span
                      ><span class="whatsapp-icon"></span>
                      <span class="whatsapp-content"> Whatsapp</span>
                      </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that is causing this is that you have put the whole content inside the , this way everything will be clickable. Try using the  with your text here and the  **below**, both inside a div, then style the dive as you want.

```
 <label style="display: flex; align-items: center">
```

It's a better practice to don't use inline style, this way you can just make something like this:

```
<div class="label">
<label for="test"> your text here </label>
<input type="checkbox" id="test" name="test">
</div>-
```

The **for=""** in the label and the **id** in the input is to link each other.